# What permissions I need to create queue storage trigger function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, queuetrigger

I am new to Azure Functions and I want to create a queue trigger Function to consume the items in specific queue. But when I create queue trigger function in vscode, it keeps show that I lack some permissions.

```
The client 'live.com#***@gmail.com' with object id '***' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' over scope '/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/***' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

The permissions I am now obtaining for this queue are as follows:
[image: permissions I have for this queue]

The permissions I am now obtaining for the storage account are as follows:
[image: permissions I have for this storage account]

I am confused that which kind of permissions I need to create a queue triggered function to consume items in specific queue?

Thank you!

Comment: did that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a function from VS Code using the Azure SDK, it will try to get the access key of the storage: by default this how you can authenticate to the storage. The error you're receiving is saying that you don't have permission to list the storage access keys.

From this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal#use-the-account-access-key), these are the roles that has the `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listkeys/action` RBAC action:

- The [Reader and Data Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader-and-data-access) role
- The [Storage Account Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-account-contributor) role
- The Azure Resource Manager [Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) role
- The Azure Resource Manager [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner) role